# How to do multiple not like statements sql server seeking performance?

Tags: sql-server

I work with SQL Server 2008 r2 and I have the following statement:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE field NOT LIKE '%YIU%'
AND field NOT LIKE '%DGFGDFGDF%'
AND field NOT LIKE '%FG%'
AND field NOT LIKE '%HJH%'
AND field NOT LIKE '%ERTY%'
AND field NOT LIKE '%ASDF%'
```

I would like to use the perfect statement for performance so I searched and I tried `NOT REGEXP` but It does not exist on SQL Server.

Does anybody knows which is the way to do it?

Comment: What RegEx would you possibly want to run here?  What do these have in common?

Comment: When you have leading wildcards like this there is little you can do. Think about a phone book. How can you quickly find all names that don't contain the letter "s"? You can't because you have to look at every single name. Such is this query.

Comment: @SeanLange Great analogy

Answer (score 0):

This is not going to be pretty or fast no matter how you try and do it.

Without more details, my suggestion would be to convert your `and ... not like` to `not ( ... or like ...)` and see if that changes the performance at all.

```
select * 
from table
where not (
     field LIKE '%YIU%'
    --or field LIKE '%DGFGDFGDF%' /* covered by '%FG%' */
    or field LIKE '%FG%'
    or field LIKE '%HJH%'
    or field LIKE '%ERTY%'
    or field LIKE '%ASDF%'
  )
```

---

What is the datatype and size of `field` ?